# The second argument of Signature

Tags: undocumented

I've noticed that `Signature` can have an undocumented second argument. What does it do?

```
Signature[{1,2,3,4}, ?]
```

Answer (score 15):

It should be a comparison function. One can simulate the standard behavior by

```
Signature[{1, 2, 3}, If[#1 < #2, True, 0] &]
Signature[{2, 1, 3}, If[#1 < #2, True, 0] &]
Signature[{1, 1, 3}, If[#1 < #2, True, 0] &]
(* 1 *)
(* -1 *)
(* 0 *)
```

If the first argument is less than the second we return `True` (or `False`, it doesn't matter!), otherwise we can return everything except `True` and `False`.

**Update:**

Sometimes it returns `0` instead of `1` or `-1`. For example,

```
a = {52579, 13723};
Signature[a]
(* -1 *)
Signature[a, If[#1 < #2, True, 0] &]
(* 0 *)
```

I've found that `Signature` has 2 phases:

1. Check up for duplicates. If duplicates are found then return `0`.
2. If there is no duplicates then calculate the signature.

At the first phase `Signature` compares hashes instead of the direct values of elements (I think it is an optimization for non-numerical lists). `Hash`es of `52579` and `13723` are the same:

```
Hash[52579]
Hash[13723]
(* 8900173879719767389 *)
(* 8900173879719767389 *)
```

So I should return something instead of `0`

```
If[#1 < #2, True, ?] &
```

Any ideas?

P.S. V8 and earlier have another `Hash` function so the "magic" numbers are different. For example, `{34064, 32232}`.

Comment: Very interesting.  How did you discover this? (+1 of course.)

Comment: I'm finding cases where your code doesn't match the output of `Signature`.  I haven't isolated it yet but here's an example: `SeedRandom[13];
a = RandomInteger[1*^10, 1*^5];` now `Signature[a]` gives `-1` while `Signature[a, If[#1 < #2, True, 0] &]` gives `0`.  Ideas?
Signature[a, If[#1 < #2, True, 0] &]

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've  discovered this when I debug [my code](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18802/13509) at codegolf.SE. I accidentally wrote `MapIndexed[Signature,A,{2}]` instead of `Map[Signature,A,{2}]`. It doesn't return any error, but it returns a wrong signature. Then I was surprised to find that the `Signature[list, something]` returns `2 Boole[Mod[Length[list], 4] < 2] - 1` if `list` has no duplicates and `0` otherwise!

Comment: Here is a shorter example where your code does not match the default: `a = {49914, 54968, 11840, 69457, 40872}` -- can you confirm this problem on your system?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I confirm this in v6 and v8, but not in v9.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard v9 also has magic numbers, e.g. `a={52579, 13723}`.

Comment: I *really* hope this gets an answer, has been bugging me for the better part of a year (when I made a similar typo mistake but still saw results). I `Sowed` the second argument and observed it appears to be pair lists, tried various ordering functions, etc. to no avail. I *thought* it might have something to do with counting inversions, left it at that. Are the MM staff that are here "allowed" to post such information? Surely a peek by one of them at the source could put this to bed.